# Remover Botão em função do javascript

Tags: javascript

Há como remover ou desabilitar o botão (cancelar) da função prompt do javascript?

Comment: sim, utilize um `alert()`

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [link do SOe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669884/javascript-prompt-box-without-the-cancel-button)

Comment: outra alternativa é usar bibliotecas do tipo [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No momento não é possível desabilitar o botão, mas uma solução poderia ser forçar a pessoa a escrever abrindo outro prompt quando o inicial for cancelado:

```js
function noRefuse() {
  do {
    x = prompt("Responda minha pergunta!")
  } while(!x)
}

var botao = document.getElementById('prompt')

botao.addEventListener('click', noRefuse);
```

```html
<input type='button' id='prompt' value='Prompt'>
```

Nesse caso, se a pessoa cancelar ou recusar, ele vai abrir outro prompt (assim como se responder em branco).

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde amigos!

**Ainda não é possível alterar os dialogs gerados através da window** segue [Html spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-prompt)

Tentando resolver seu problema você pode usar alguma lib para gerar dialogs através do DOM.